# My thesis proposal

Tags: graduate-school, thesis, university, language, linguistics

I'm a student in Iran studying [English Language Teaching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teaching_English_as_a_second_or_foreign_language) (M.A.) at University. Before pursuing English at the university level, I was an engineer, so I have a background knowledge of math. I've developed a strong interest in [Astro-linguistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astrolinguistics). Considering that English Language Teaching is a branch of [applied linguistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Applied_linguistics), I am wondering if it is academically reasonable to the following topic in astro-linguistics for my thesis research?

Exploring the Hypothetical: Astrolinguistics and its Implications for Language Studies"

Comment: You should not vandalize your own question, especially after it has been answered. By doing so, and by badly copying your previous question, you have broken all the links I inserted ... and deleted the answer. If you want to change your question you should simply edit it. You can even indicate what edits you have made in response to answers or comments.

Comment: This is a question for your advisor.

Comment: Your first question was closed for a reason. We cannot make decisions on your research and rephrasing the question does not change that. You (or somebody else) may [edit] the question such that it becomes about how to make the decision (which is also what was answered). Please see [this FAQ](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3406/7734).

Answer (score 1):

For a research thesis, you require considerably more than a topic, even before you begin. You really need a research question. I am not suggesting that you should *already* have a research question. However the issue of whether your research will be sufficient foundation for a masters or doctoral thesis, will be predicated on the research question(s) that you try to answer, rather than the notional topic.

A further issue you are going to face is whether you can find an advisor who feels themselves capable of  supervising a thesis in [astrolinguistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astrolinguistics). I don't imagine that there are many schools around the world that have appropriate people. Finally, it is the combination of you, a potential advisor, and the combination of interests and skills that will determine the viability of any topic in astrolinguistics ... not the the consensus opinion on SE Academia.

Do some research, develop a list of potential universities/schools, look for potential supervisors, consider the likelihood of you being accepted into any of the places of interest, and go from there.